# The fastest way to read a ~500000 line Text

Tags: java, string, text, bufferedreader

I'm currently writing a small parser for files of the size ~500000 a very simple syntax, but reading the file is taking ages although the file is only 10 MB big.
Currently I have

```
public static String read(File file) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String currentLine = "";
    String text = "";
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            text += currentLine + "\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

As you might notice I'm inserting a line break on the end...
This line break is needed for parsing...

What should I do in order to speed the process of reading up?
I need the file in a single String...

Comment: Tried using a stringbuilder?

Comment: tl;dr: use a `StringBuilder` or the whole thing will take O(n^2).

Comment: No... I'll try that! Thanks

Comment: Not only that but its a huge memory waste as each time you increase the length of the string you're creating a NEW string, where as a StringBuilder is capable of increasing in size.

Comment: Do you actually need the whole file in memory in order to parse it? If you could parse line by line instead, that would avoid having to use a StringBuilder at all...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sometimes I need to jump backwards in Code... To get the class name, or forward, in order to check if the rest of the line are just spaces and then jump back

Comment: Instead of reading line by line you can read a file with chunck of memory, lets say 4k. If you read your file with chunck of buffers, you can reduce a time to read it.

Comment: Are you doing line-reading to control the line break character? If not, and you need the entire file in memory, use block-reading, not line-reading. That is, on top of using `StringBuilder`, which is the primary need.

Comment: "Rest of the line" sounds like it would just be on the same line. Even if you need a buffer of a few lines, that could still be *much* more efficient than reading the whole file.

Comment: Good Point... I'll look into that later...

Comment: The fastest way to read a file in is not StringBuilder but NIO/Files:

    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);